# Can you modify a C struct from lua?

Tags: c, lua

I want to be able to have this Lua code:

```lua
function myfunc(s)
    print(s.value)
    s.value = 7
end
```

And it should work with this C(++) code:

```
struct MyStruct {
    float value;
};

void func() {
    MyStruct var;
    var.value = 5;

    lua_getglobal(L, "myfunc");
    // push `var` to lua, somehow

    lua_call(L, 1, 0); // prints "5"

    // now, var.value is 7
    assert(var.value == 7);
}
```

How would I push `var` onto the stack such that the lua code can modify its variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Lua doesn't have a built-in way to expose the contents of `struct`s through tables, so doing so is a bit of a manual process. Here's an example of a complete program that does what you want:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <lua5.3/lua.h>
#include <lua5.3/lualib.h>
#include <lua5.3/lauxlib.h>

struct MyStruct {
    float value;
};

int MyStruct_index(lua_State *L) {
    struct MyStruct *t = (struct MyStruct *)luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "MyStruct");
    const char *k = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
    if(!strcmp(k, "value")) {
        lua_pushnumber(L, t->value);
    } else {
        lua_pushnil(L);
    }
    return 1;
}

int MyStruct_newindex(lua_State *L) {
    struct MyStruct *t = (struct MyStruct *)luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "MyStruct");
    const char *k = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
    if(!strcmp(k, "value")) {
        t->value = luaL_checknumber(L, 3);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return luaL_argerror(L, 2,
                             lua_pushfstring(L, "invalid option '%s'", k));
    }
}

struct MyStruct *MyStruct_new(lua_State *L) {
    struct MyStruct *var = (struct MyStruct *)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof *var);
    luaL_setmetatable(L, "MyStruct");
    return var;
}

void func(lua_State *L) {
    // Since this is allocated inside of Lua, it will be garbage collected,
    // so we don't need to worry about freeing it
    struct MyStruct *var = MyStruct_new(L);
    var->value = 5;

    lua_getglobal(L, "myfunc");
    lua_pushvalue(L, -2); // push `var` to lua, somehow

    lua_call(L, 1, 0); // prints "5"

    // now, var->value is 7
    assert(var->value == 7);
}

int main(void) {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    // One-time setup that needs to happen before you first call MyStruct_new
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "MyStruct");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, MyStruct_index);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, MyStruct_newindex);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__newindex");
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    luaL_dostring(L, "function myfunc(s) print(s.value) s.value = 7 end");
    func(L);

    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

To support more fields, you'd have to add them to `MyStruct_index` and `MyStruct_newindex`. If you want `pairs` to work on it, then you'd need to add a `__pairs` metamethod too. In general, though, exposing getters and setters is usually preferred over an approach like this one.

If you want to allocate your `struct MyStruct` somewhere other than inside of Lua, then you could add an extra layer of indirection everywhere it's used, like this:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <lua5.3/lua.h>
#include <lua5.3/lualib.h>
#include <lua5.3/lauxlib.h>

struct MyStruct {
    float value;
};

int MyStruct_index(lua_State *L) {
    struct MyStruct **t = (struct MyStruct **)luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "MyStruct");
    const char *k = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
    if(!strcmp(k, "value")) {
        lua_pushnumber(L, (*t)->value);
    } else {
        lua_pushnil(L);
    }
    return 1;
}

int MyStruct_newindex(lua_State *L) {
    struct MyStruct **t = (struct MyStruct **)luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "MyStruct");
    const char *k = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
    if(!strcmp(k, "value")) {
        (*t)->value = luaL_checknumber(L, 3);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return luaL_argerror(L, 2,
                             lua_pushfstring(L, "invalid option '%s'", k));
    }
}

void MyStruct_push(lua_State *L, struct MyStruct *var) {
    struct MyStruct **t = (struct MyStruct **)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof *t);
    *t = var;
    luaL_setmetatable(L, "MyStruct");
}

void func(lua_State *L) {
    struct MyStruct var;
    var.value = 5;

    lua_getglobal(L, "myfunc");
    MyStruct_push(L, &var); // push `var` to lua, somehow

    lua_call(L, 1, 0); // prints "5"

    // now, var.value is 7
    assert(var.value == 7);

    // WARNING! `var` is about to go out of scope! If Lua uses the userdata
    // that references it beyond this point, it's Undefined Behavior! Make
    // sure that it didn't keep a copy of it!
}

int main(void) {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    // One-time setup that needs to happen before you first call MyStruct_new
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "MyStruct");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, MyStruct_index);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, MyStruct_newindex);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__newindex");
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    luaL_dostring(L, "function myfunc(s) print(s.value) s.value = 7 end");
    func(L);

    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

But this is dangerous! If the Lua userdata outlives the object that it points to, Undefined Behavior will result!

Comment: Thanks! Could I use a lightuserdata if I already had the struct created and don't want to malloc a new one?

Comment: @cry0genic No, because lightuserdata can't have metatables. You'd have to switch to a getter/setter function approach to do that. You can do it with a full userdata that carries a pointer, though (see edit).

Comment: But all lightuserdatum can have a common metatable.  This might fit OP's needs.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That would only be safe to do if lightuserdata were never used for anything else, but that's not the case even in Lua itself: for example, `debug.upvalueid` returns one.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - Yes, debug.upvalueid returns a lightuserdata.  But its indexing is not defined, so there is no problem here.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff With full userdata, `luaL_checkuserdata` can make sure it's the right kind of userdata before operating on it, and throw an error if not. With light userdata, there's no such check, so doing `debug.upvalueid(f, 1).value = 123` would corrupt random memory.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - Why OP would apply indexing to arbitrary lightuserdata?  His code works only with his own lightuserdata.  And BTW type checking could be implemented inside indexing metamethods (if really needed).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff He wouldn't want to, but the risk is that he accidentally could, and usually you don't have to worry about accidental memory corruption when you're writing Lua. And how could you do the type checking in the metamethod exactly? I can't think of a way.

Comment: Type checking could be done if lightuserdata is built as a reference to an object created by user.  The object knows its index, and an array of all objects' addresses could be used to lookup the index and make sure the lightuserdata contains valid address.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff How is having an outside array of all valid pointers any better than just using a full userdata, though?

Comment: 1) Full userdatum lifetime is unpredictable and beyond C programmer's control.  2) `you don't have to worry about accidental memory corruption when you're writing Lua` - if you don't use debug library (which could easily crash Lua VM).