# How to add namespaces to Lua?

Tags: c++, lua

I'm using Lua in a game engine that I'm working on. I'd like to give Lua a way to get and set the position of the entity that the script is sitting on. The script is a component that contains a pointer to the entity that contains it. From Lua, I'd like to be able to type:

```lua
print(transform.position.x)
transform.position.x = 10
```

I've written a getter and setter for position, by I'd like them to be contained under `transform.position`, and preferably not be getter and setters at all but rather behave more like public members. My current getter and setter looks like this:

```cpp
int getXPosition(lua_State* L) {
    lua_pushnumber(L, Script::currentEntity->get<Transform>().position.x);

    return 1;
}
```

So, how would this be done, if possible at all?

Comment: You can write a metatable for `transform.position` and translate `.x` to a function call bound to a C API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you modify a C struct from lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095922/can-you-modify-a-c-struct-from-lua)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it may be done with [userdata](https://www.lua.org/pil/28.1.html) and [metatables](https://www.lua.org/pil/28.2.html).

More details:

1. Register metatable that will be a "class" for the `position` object and register `"__index"` and `"__newindex"` metamethods for it:

   ```
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "position_metatable");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, &position__index);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, &position__newindex);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__newindex");
    lua_pop(L, 1);
   ```
2. Write function `position__index` (it is getter). This is regular C Api function, it takes 2 arguments: the `position` userdata and a field name. If the field name is `"x"`, the function should return the value of the `x` field.
3. Write function `position__newindex` (it is setter). This is regular C Api function, it takes 3 arguments: the `position` userdata, field name and a value to write. If the field is `"x"`, teh function should write the value to the `x` field.
4. To pass the `position` object from native code to script, create userdata and set the `"position_metatable"` as a metatable for the userdata, see [28.2 – Metatables](https://www.lua.org/pil/28.2.html) for example.
5. Access to the field as `transform.position.x`.

Comment: What do you mean by the "`position` object (instance)?" Is this my Vec2 class? Do I need to expose that to Lua?

Comment: By object instance I mean created userdata with assigned `position_metatable` as a metatable. One of the way to implement that userdata is to store pointer to Script::currentEntity or Script::currentEntity->get<Transform>().position in the userdata record.

Comment: `transform.position:x` is not syntax error, it is called _colon operator_ in lua and it is syntax sugar for implicit passing self to an object, see http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html

Comment: This syntax is applicable only to methods, not to fields.